# Unable to change rotation in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've been working on a project in Unity3D and found a javascript that makes the enemies follow the player. This is the script:

```
var target : Transform; //the enemy's target
var moveSpeed = 3; //move speed
var rotationSpeed = 3; //speed of turning

var myTransform : Transform; //current transform data of this enemy

function Awake()
{
    myTransform = transform; //cache transform data for easy access/preformance
}

function Start()
{
     target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform; //target the player

}

function Update () {
    //rotate to look at the player
    myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,
    Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);

    //move towards the player
    myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


}
```

When the enemies "rotate to look at the player" they rotate from a horizontal position to a vertical. How can I change the script in order to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a secon parameter at Quaternion.LookRotation

You may use :

Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position, **Vector3.up**)
or
Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position, **transform.up**)